# Different way to store local data in a vb.net application

Tags: vb.net, windows-xp

I have a vb.net application that should work on Win XP sp3.

How can I store local data and use it (to store and fetch and update data) what are the different why (local db, xml file, ...) ?

I already tried with local DB but i have problems of compatibility with windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

Using DB is the better and common way, you can use `XML` instead. here you can refer an alternate method called [Object Serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms233843.aspx). it is nothing but

> The process of converting an object into a stream of bytes in order to store the object or transmit it to memory, a database, or a file. Its main purpose is to save the state of an object in order to be able to recreate it when needed. The reverse process is called deserialization.